# Capitalization and acronyms

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will capitalize any words but leave any uppercase abbreviations and acronyms as they are.

For example, I'd like 'london' to become 'London' but 'LA' to remain as it is. Ideally also, any two character words would be uppercased, e.g., 'la' → 'LA'.

It's easy enough to do the capitalization bit, but the abbreviations/acronyms are eluding me. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Re: "It's easy enough to do the capitalization bit, [...]": Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: How should the expression deal with two letter words like "going from here **to** there"?

Comment: post some representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: here's what I was using to capitalize:

    python -c "print raw_input().title()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\b.\B/\u&/g;s/\b..\b/\U&/g' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

$ sed 's/\b.\B/\u&/g;s/\b..\b/\U&/g' file
Lorem Ipsum IS Simply Dummy Text OF The Printing And Typesetting Industry. 
Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry'S Standard Dummy Text Ever Since The 1500s, 
When AN Unknown Printer Took A Galley OF Type And Scrambled IT TO Make A Type Specimen Book.
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro, that does exactly what I was looking for!